# Pass Parameters to AddHostedService

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, windows-services

I am writing a .Net Core windows service and here is a snippet of code:

```
internal static class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var isService = !(Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--console"));

            var builder = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<IntegrationService>();
                });

            if (isService)
            {
                await builder.RunAsServiceAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                await builder.RunConsoleAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to pass some parameters to my service i.e. `IntegrationService` - how I can send parameters to my service?

Comment: You can pass in the factory method. `services.AddHostedService<IntegrationService>(sp => new IntegrationService(...));`. The `sp` represents the `IServiceProvider` which you can also use to get information to instanciate your hosted-service. If you need other options consider adding a config option or something similar which you can then inject using the constructor so you don't have to manually do it like that. This overload exists in .net core 3 preview6, but not in .net core 2.2. Because you didn't specify what version you're using I commented this.

Comment: @Joelius there is no overload for AddHostedService as Kirk Larkin said.

Regarding second approach can you elaborate more in answer

Comment: You can emulate the overload. It's just a wrapper around `AddTransient<IHostedService, TWhatever>()`, which of course *does* support the factory func approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before `.net core 3` you can use a config class which you can inject into the service via DI.

Your config class could look like this:

```
class IntegrationConfig
{
    public int Timeout { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to add this config to the DI-system:

```
services.AddSingleton(new IntegrationConfig
{
    Timeout = 1234,
    Name = "Integration name"
});
```

In the class `IntegrationService` you need to add a constructor which takes an object of the config:

```
public IntegrationService(IntegrationConfig config)
{
    // setup with config or simply store config
}
```

That's basically all you need. It's not the prettiest solution in my opinion and in `.net core 3` 
you can simply use a factory func to add the HostedService but I think something like this is the best choice 
if you're on `.net core 2.2` or below.

EDIT:

In the comments Kirk Larkin mentions this:

> You can emulate the overload. It's just a wrapper around AddTransient(), which of course does support the factory func approach.

For this you might want to look at the current overload which is accessable [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Hosting/Abstractions/src/ServiceCollectionHostedServiceExtensions.cs):

```
/// <summary>
/// Add an <see cref="IHostedService"/> registration for the given type.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="THostedService">An <see cref="IHostedService"/> to register.</typeparam>
/// <param name="services">The <see cref="IServiceCollection"/> to register with.</param>
/// <param name="implementationFactory">A factory to create new instances of the service implementation.</param>
/// <returns>The original <see cref="IServiceCollection"/>.</returns>
public static IServiceCollection AddHostedService<THostedService>(this IServiceCollection services, Func<IServiceProvider, THostedService> implementationFactory)
    where THostedService : class, IHostedService
{
    services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IHostedService>(implementationFactory));

    return services;
}
```

Note that the [last commit that changed this file](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/commit/6e92fcad99b6a6e882ac8dc5ad817b558f603597) was on June 3rd and is tagged for preview6 and preview7 of .net core 3. Because I've never heard of `TryAddEnumerable` and am no microsoft employee, I don't know if you can directly translate that.

Just from looking at the [current implementation of `AddTransient`](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/DependencyInjection/DI.Abstractions/src/ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.cs) and going down the rabbit hole a few files more, I sadly can't draw the lines well enough to be able to give you the exact functionality you're currently able to get with `.net core 3`.
The workaround I gave still works and seems acceptable depending on the situation.

Comment: hello, could you specify for .net core 3.1 what is the way to use a factory function

Comment: @Serge please refer to the other answers, this answer was written for versions prior to 3.0. It's been a long time since I wrote this answer and OPs answer should be preferred IMO.

Answer (score 25):

Small update on Joelius answer for .Net Core 3

Given an HostedService with this constructor mixing parameters (`TimeSpan`) and services (`ILogger<StatusService>`, `IHttpClientFactory`)

```
public StatusService(
            TimeSpan cachePeriod,
            ILogger<StatusService> logger,
            IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
```

You can in your Startup.cs add it to your HostedService like this :

```
services.AddHostedService 
    (serviceProvider => 
        new StatusService(
            TimeSpan.FromDays(1), 
            serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<StatusService>>(), 
            serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>()));
```

Answer (score 21):

While the answers above are correct, they do have the downside that you can't use DI in the Services Constructor anymore.

What I did instead was:

```cs
class Settings {
  public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
class SomeService : IHostedService {
  public SomeService (string instanceId, IOptionsMonitor<Settings> optionsMonitor) {
    var settings = optionsMonitor.Get(instanceId);
  }
}
```

```cs
services.Configure<Settings>("Instance1", (s) => s.Url = "http://google.com");
services.Configure<Settings>("Instance2", (s) => s.Url = "http://facebook.com");

services.AddSingleton<IHostedService>(x => 
 ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<SomeService>(x, "Instance1")
);

services.AddSingleton<IHostedService>(x => 
 ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<SomeService>(x, "Instance2")
);
```

This creates named settings for each instance and passes the named settings name to the HostedService.
If you want multiple Services with the same Class and different parameters make sure to use **AddSingleton** instead of **AddHostedService** as AddHostedService will add only one instance of the same Type which will result in only one instance being started!

Comment: This is arguably the best solution when your class requires things like ILogger and IOptions

Answer (score 9):

What Joelius answered is correct although there is another way of doing this

```
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService>(provider => new IntegrationService("Test"));
```

Comment: This will probably give you most of the functionality but can you assure that this gives you the exact same behaviour as `AddHostedService`? From looking at the source for a bit I was not able to confirm that these calls are equal :/

Comment: Yes, It gives same behavior as `AddHostedService`